# Formatting data in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, formatting, code-behind

I've got a dropdown control on a form.  The results of this dropdown need to be written to a hidden textbox, but when they're written to the textbox it needs to be in the format "XX.XX".  So, if the user selects "1.0", it needs to be written to the textbox as "01.00".

I'm a native Access/VBA programmer, and it's fairly easy to do in VBA.  How would I do this in C# code-behind?

What I have now is:

```
    protected void ddlCIT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCIT.Text = ddlCIT.SelectedValue;
    }
```

This was before I knew about this requirement., so it doesn't address the formatting issue at all.  I'm sure it's got to be something like:

```
txtCIT.Text = Format(ddlCIT.SelectedValue, "##.##");
```

or something, but I just can't figure it out.  None of the examples I've found were doing anything close to what I need.

**EDIT**

As per asven's answer, I've now got the following code:

```
 string ddlCITVal = ddlCIT.SelectedValue.ToString();
 txtCIT.Text = string.Format("{0:#0.0#}", ddlCITVal);
 string blearg = string.Format("{0:0.0#}", ddlCITVal);
```

Both my textbox and my string "blearg" show a result of "2.0" in the Immediate window when I select "2.0" from the dropdown.  I also tried using "{0:00.00}" in the format clause with identical results.

I'm using VS2012 if that matters.

Comment: you are looking for string.Format

Comment: Can you tell me, given the above information, what the actual line of code would be?  I'm really still a C# novice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
string.Format("{0:00.00}", ddlCIT.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Your missing quotes around `{0:00.00}`.

Comment: It's not working.  Do you think I have to convert ddlCIT.SelectedValue to a string or something?  Right now the textbox is still identical to what's in the dropdown.

Comment: You can try to just do ddlCIT.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: @JohnnyBones You shouldn't have to convert it to a string.  Is your drop down list bound to an array of strings or objects?  If it is just a list of strings your may want to try `string.Format("{0:00.00}", ddlCIT.Text);`.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm using C# 2012?  Because it's still keeping the same format as the dropdown.

Comment: I actually had to convert to a double and then back to a string, but this helped me get to that point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could go one step further and use a custom textbox.  This allows you to have validation and formatting built in:

```
public class NumDoubTextbox : TextBox
{
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            double temp = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(value, out temp))
                //Formatting as a float then padding left with 0's should give the format you want
                base.Text = temp.ToString("F2").PadLeft(5,'0');
            else
                //Handle invalid input here. 
                base.Text = "--.--";
        }
    }
}
```

You can put this in a separate project and compile it and have it included in the toolbox so that it can be used at design time.